# Convergent sequence of points

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, geometry, complex-numbers, alternative-proof

Let  $n\ge 0$ and  $A_0, A_1, A_2$  3 points of the plane. We define recursively $A_{n+3}$ as the barycenter of the system $\{(A_n;2);(A_{n+1};1);(A_{n+2};1)\}$. Show that the sequence $(A_n)$ converges and find $A_{\infty}$.

> My try: I define $z_n$ as the affix of $A_n$. This provide the relation: $4z_{n+3}-z_{n+2}-z_{n+1}-2z_n=0$. Solving this gives: $z_n=\lambda+\mu\rho_1^n+\nu\rho_2^n$. Since $ |\rho_{1,2}|<1$ the sequence converges and the limit will be $\lambda$ which I can find.

Is there an alternative prove specially with using geometry tools only?

Comment: If you can show that the barycenter lies within the triangle formed by the previous 3 points, and also show that there is fixed ratio $r < 1$ such that the longest side of the new triangle is less than $r$ times the longest side of the old, then you can prove that you have a nested sequence of compact sets with diameter going to $0$, which garantees a unique limit point.